# Automated way to convert all class methods to public methods

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have to modify a fairly extensive class so I can use it in a chain of inheritance, so as a first step I have to migrate all function names to the interface so they are available for inheritance. Is there a better way to do this than manually going through my `.m` file and copying each name over one by one?

Comment: No, there shouldn't. And you shouldn't publish all methods to the interface, because you need them for overwriting. This doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad then what should I do if I want to have a parent class with helpful methods that all children will use?

Comment: Put that helpful methods into the interface.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should redesign your class hierarchy.

I would ask, however, is subclassing really appropriate?  Do your subclasses adhere to the requirements of a subclass, in particular [Liskov's Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)?

However, ObjC does not require that methods be known in advance for polymorphism to work, and the only concept of "private" methods is in the exposure to header files.

That said, if I were forced to do what you are proposing, I would create a protocol with the methods that are intended to be implemented.

```
@protocol MyAPI
- (void)foo;
- (void)bar:(id)bar withBlarg:(id)blarg;
@end
```

Then, you can have whatever classes you like declare conformity to that protocol.

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject<MyAPI>
@end
```

Then, if the class already implements the required methods, you have nothing to do.  Otherwise, implement the methods in the classes so that they conform properly to the protocol API.

Now, let's say that you have some method that expects to receive an object that conforms to the `MyAPI` protocol.

```
- (void)something:(id<MyAPI>)object {
    [object foo];
    [object bar:self.bar withBlarg:self.blarg];
}
```

This means that any object could be passed into `something` as long as it conformed to the protocol, and does not require any form of inheritance.

Furthermore, ObjectiveC does not support multiple inheritance, but you can conform to as many protocols as you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but isn't it a bit strange for you, without knowing anything about what I'm doing, to ask right away if I should even be using inheritance? Protocols make no sense when I want to have an bunch of objects that share many methods and are indeed subclasses of the same grouping. By the way if you are suggesting using protocols to effectively implement multiple inheritance THAT sounds like a REALLY bad idea.

Comment: @helloB - Nope, it's not strange at all.  It's the very first question you should ask every time you think inheritance is the answer.  Sometimes inheritance is the right answer.  Most of the time it is not.  However, you do what you want.  It's your code, and your problem.

Comment: we're talking about an object oriented language where the whole ios sdk is extensively built on inheritance....

Comment: Inheritance is one of many object oriented programming concepts, to be used like any other tool; as appropriate.  Your question is full of red flags.  You want to inherit from an existing class that apparently was not originally intended for that purpose, or this would not even be an issue.  The class is "extensive" which implies that it likely has numerous responsibilities.  You now want to use the class as the base of a "chain of inheritance."  No, I don't know the details of what you are doing, but I've seen these warning signs before; enough to know that the question should be asked.